# Installing FreeBSD 13.1 fails right after booting

Tags: boot, freebsd, system-installation

Machine:

1. motherboard: asus tuf gaming z490-plus(wifi)
2. cpu: i7-10700K
3. ram: 32gb ddr4
4. no dedicated GPU

What I've tried?

I've put on my pendrive (sandisk) with installed Ventoy, these files:

- FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso
- FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img
- FreeBSD-13.1-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso
- FreeBSD-13.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso
- FreeBSD-13.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img
- GhostBSD-22.06.18.iso
- hello-0.7.0_0G160-FreeBSD-13.0-amd64.iso

Also on my second pendrive (samsung) I've "burned" FreeBSD-13.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img by using Rufus with Windows.

Each time with 13.1 version the issue is the same:

Booting starts and I see menu with FreeBSD ascii art, I can choose between multi user / single user and so on.
Both options shortly lead me to black screen with white rectangle ascii character at the top left corner of screen and mouse pointer (arrow) that I can move around - and it stays that forever.
I can press CTRL + ALT + DEL and then it restarts whole machine.

With 13.0 version it is similiar, but it hangs a little bit earlier with EFI Framebuffer data showed on screen.

Only `hello-0.7.0_0G160-FreeBSD-13.0-amd64.iso` boots completly to usable OS.

How can I install pure FreeBSD 13.1 on my machine?

Booting "FreeBSD-13.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img" by pendrive, video clip:
Two mirrors:

- [Video clip, gfycat mirror](https://gfycat.com/granularelementaryharrierhawk)
- [Video clip, uploadify mirror](https://uploadify.net/9cda014ec58c7fd1/YouCut_20221204_140433286.mp4)

[image: stays that forever]

---

It looks like it's common problem:

### https://www.reddit.com/r/freebsd/comments/tye20z/black_screen_an_mouse/

Comment: I've found solution. All you need is enable UEFI Boot in your BIOS settings. Follow that instructions on YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xjPCUJ_h0o